# unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am using [ffmpeg](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library for android.

I am passing one `ffmpeg` command for convert video format from `.mp4` to `.avi`

```
ffmpeg -r 20 -i /storage/emulated/0/WisperMedia/WisperVideos/sample.mp4 -b:v 20M /storage/emulated/0/WisperMedia/WisperVideos/output.avi
```

But I am getting error like

```
    09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343): FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/WisperMedia/WisperVideos/sample.mp4':
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   Metadata:
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     major_brand     : isom
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     minor_version   : 0
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     compatible_brands: isom3gp4
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     creation_time   : 2015-09-23 03:50:16
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):   Duration: 00:00:01.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14737 kb/s
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 11819 kb/s, SAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 29.79 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     Metadata:
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       rotate          : 90
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       creation_time   : 2015-09-23 03:50:16
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       handler_name    : VideoHandle
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     Side data:
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):     Metadata:
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       creation_time   : 2015-09-23 03:50:16
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343):       handler_name    : SoundHandle
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343): [NULL @ 0x41f7f420] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ffmpeg'
09-23 09:29:41.525: E/Home(31343): ffmpeg: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Are you sure the output corresponds to the posted command? Because the log says it tries to read a PNG file: `/storage/emulated/0/WisperMedia/WisperImages/Zq3vbi3ZY3ML.png`

Comment: Are you by any chance passing multiple `ffmpeg` commands at once? This can only happen if you have a trailing `ffmpeg` on the initial command, ie: `ffmpeg -i something -o something ffmpeg ...`

Comment: No @aergistal. I am not passing multiple ffmpeg command. Though I will check

Comment: you saved my life thank you so much @aergistal . your hint is very useful . actually in this ffmpeg library we dont have to add ffmpeg in command . it automatically adding ffmpeg in command so I have to pass command without ffmpeg. thank you .  :)

Comment: Thanks a lot to @aergistal, i also did not knew that ffmpeg wasnt needed!

Comment: @llogan sure, done

Answer (score 27):

These kind of errors are usually caused by unintended leading or trailing arguments in the `ffmpeg` command. If you are using a third-party library that acts as a wrapper to `ffmpeg` you must check its documentation and output since it may automatically add arguments (like the path to the `ffmpeg` binary for example).

In this particular case `ffmpeg` is seen as an unknown output. Some incorrect commands that could raise this error include:

- `ffmpeg -i [input] -o [output] ffmpeg ...`
- `ffmpeg ffmpeg ...`

Comment: This was the case for me. I am using `nl.bravobit:android-ffmpeg:1.1.5` library and it was appending ffmpeg automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Same error may suggest ffmpeg simply needs to be told what format to output with the -f flag, because it failed to deduce it from the output file extension.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.xxx -f flac audio.flac
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, command was sent to me by email.

In the following parameter, "-c:a", there was not a dash, but a windows character!